# Oracle select from a table where value contains an underscore

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I have a query where i need to select from a table where value starts with M_. Problem is that the underscore is a wildcard character in oracle. So take following data in the description field:

```
M1
M_1
M2
M_2
```

When i run following query all fields are returned:

```
select description from table where description like 'M_%'
```

I tried escaping with following query which returns no results:

```
select description from table where description like 'M\_%'
```

The results i am looking for are only descriptions that start with M_ so expected results are:

```
M_1
M_2
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the escape character explicitly:

```
select description from table where description like 'M\_%' escape '\'
```

This means you can use an alternative character in place of the backslash. For example:

```
select description from table where description like 'M$_%' escape '$'
```